# How do I make a test account on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, account-management

I want to see just some people's pages and test some features of Facebook.
I tried to make a temporary account, but it needs my phone number or an image of my certification, but I don't want to provide these.

Is there another way to make a Facebook account for my purpose?

Comment: Have you used the same email address?

Comment: I have not there an account yet, I can make one but for verifying it asks me my phone number or an image, and I don't want to provide these

Comment: Your account name should not contain any numbers. Ex abcd123 - account wont get created, try with "abc"

Answer (score 4):

[Facebook offers developers test accounts](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/35/) with the following conditions:

> - Test accounts won't be able to see real Facebook users and vice versa. You can make an existing account a test account, but if that account is friends with a real account, each user will disappear from the other's list of friends.
> - Our customer support team won't disable test accounts for being fake, but test accounts may be disabled for violating any other reason that a real account would be disabled.
> - Only real accounts may be listed as application owners. In other words, **you may not list a test account as the developer of an app.**

Answer (score 3):

Anyone can easily create a test Facebook account via the following page. It’s officially intended for security researchers, and there are various limitations. See the page below for more info:

https://www.facebook.com/whitehat/accounts/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the docs for creating test user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

__

**Creating**

You can create a test user associated with a particular app using the Graph API with your app access token.

**API**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
  installed=true
  &name=FULL_NAME
  &permissions=read_stream
  &method=post
  &access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**Parameters**:

You can specify whether this user has already installed your app as well as the set of permissions that your app is granted for this user by default upon creation.

**installed**: This is a Boolean parameter to specify whether your app should be installed for the test user at the time of creation. It is true by default.

**name**: this is an optional string parameter. You can specify a name for the test user you create. The specified name will also be used in the email address assigned to the test user.

**permissions**: This is a comma-separated list of extended permissions. Your app is granted these permissions for the new test user if installed is true.

**access_token**: {app_id}|{app_secret}

Response :

> {    "id": "1234...",     "access_token":"1234567..." ,
>   "login_url":"https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account..."
>   "email": "example...@tfbnw.net",   "password": "1234..." }

**id** : User id of the test user

**access_token**: You can use this access token to make API calls on behalf of the test user. This is available only if your app has been installed by the test user.

**login_url**: You can login as the test user by going to this url. This expires on first use or after one hour whichever happens first to ensure that the test accounts remain secure. You can easily refresh the login_url by simply calling the get method again.

**email**: If logging in manually (that is, not using the login_url), you can use this as the user's email address.

**password**: If logging in manually (that is, not using the login_url), you can use this as the user's password. You should store this password, as it will only be returned on the creation of the test user. This is because we don't store the password ourselves, just the hash. See this section should you need to change/reset the password.

**Error Codes**:

If you exceed the limit of test users you can create for an app you will receive an error.

> Error code: 2900 (Too many test accounts)